# Statistic for measuring amount of "reordering" between two vectors?

Tags: correlation, combinatorics, paired-data, spearman-rho

Ok, so here's the motivating situation: I have two pieces of software for which I can feed in an RNA sequence, and get out a numerical value. And while it's clear that one of the pieces of software consistently returns slightly lower values than the other, I'm really more interested in the *relative* values produced by the two programs. That is, if Program_1 says that RNA_seq_1 < RNA_seq_2, then does Program_2 also say that RNA_seq_1 < RNA_seq_2?

To this end I wrote a short R script (see below) based on the concept of ["total absolute displacement"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X0300205X) between two vectors, which assumes that two vectors contain paired values, and computes a normalized sum of the absolute difference of the ranks of each element in going from the first vector to the second. However, because we're operating on permutations here, if I'm interesting in examining the distribution of these ordering values over all length-n vectors, it takes n! time. And while that's doable for very small values of n, I'm interested in values of n in the hundreds, or thousands.

But what I really want out of all of this is some way to compare the orderings of two sets of paired values, so if there's a more straightforward way to accomplish this, I'm all ears. Thanks in advance!

Aforementioned R script:

```
reordering_metric = function(vec1, vec2){
  num_elements = length(vec1)
  summed_absolute_difference = sum(abs(rank(vec1)-rank(vec2)))
  normalization_factor = floor((num_elements^2)/2)  # restricts output to [0,1]
  return( summed_absolute_difference / normalization_factor )
}
```

Comment: Looks to me that you are looking for [concordance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient) (and [inter-rater reliability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability)  more generally)?

Comment: (1) Have you considered the Spearman correlation coefficient?  (2) Is there anything the matter with sampling from the full distribution?

Comment: Ah, you're both right, all I really need here is a simple correlational measure, I don't need to go through all the headache of generating my own distributions. Thanks!

Comment: I was badly overthinking things, all I really needed was a simple correlational measure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Looks to me that you are looking for concordance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient) (and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability more generally)? – tchakravarty

Have you considered the Spearman correlation coefficient? (2) Is there anything the matter with sampling from the full distribution? – whuber